# Keyboard shortcut for  (and individual emojis generally) on macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I'm aware of <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> to bring up the emoji selection tool.

However, I use thumbs up quite a bit, and it would be convenient to assign it to a keyboard shortcut to save going through the menu every time.

Is it possible to assign various emojis to key combinations (i.e. keyboard shortcuts)?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in System Prefs >  Keyboard > Text
It wouldn't be wise to make these single letter shortcuts, nor real words.

Here are some examples.

[image]

I've only added the full stop [period] to the beginning to sort them all together, though it is valid as a trigger at the *front*, but not at the end.
The trigger itself needs a space or punctuation afterwards to do the 'swap' [why a full stop at the end of the trigger itself is awkward]

So, like this `.ks[space]` generates  etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick (and helpful) answer. I just tried adding tu (for thumbs up) and it creates a  instead (which is great). This is definitely useful. *But* I was hoping to make it a keyboard shortcut (e.g. command + t + u). Do you know if it's possible?

Comment: Double letter shortcuts can't be done natively. Simple Cmd + one letter tend to already be used somewhere. So.. sure, this is technically possible using Automator & Applescript structure saved as a Service, it would be a nuisance to use; you'd need 'complex' triggers to not fall over other commands. I'd consider it not worth the effort, tbh.

Comment: If you wanted to play around with [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) you could swap in some emojis on the lesser-used glyphs, I suppose. For instance, swapping out Ê, usually on Opt/Shift/T, as a 'thumb'.

Comment: One additional thing I noticed about this is is seems to sync across MacBook and phone. Quite handy!

Comment: @stevec - Yup, indeed. The sometimes irritating thing is every so often the phone syncs back the original defaults… from out of the blue, & you have to delete them again. [Haven't seen this happen in a while, they may have fixed it by now] 